# defaultProps should be declared outside the class body

Tags: reactjs, typescript

everyone. I have this code which causes an error "'defaultProps' should be declared outside the class body".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './RollDice.css'; 
import Die from './Die';

class Dice extends Component {
// Face numbers passes as default props
static defaultProps = {
sides: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'],
};

constructor(props) {
super(props);

// States
this.state = {
  die1: 'one',
  die2: 'one',
  rolling: false,
};
this.roll = this.roll.bind(this);
}

roll() {
const { sides } = this.props;
this.setState({
  // Changing state upon click
  die1: sides[Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length)],
  die2: sides[Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length)],
  rolling: true,
});

// Start timer of one sec when rolling start
setTimeout(() => {
  // Set rolling to false again when time over
  this.setState({ rolling: false });
}, 1000);
}

render() {
const handleBtn = this.state.rolling ? 'RollDice-rolling' : '';
const { die1, die2, rolling } = this.state;
return (
  <div className="RollDice">
    <div className="RollDice-container">
      <Die face={die1} rolling={rolling} />
      <Die face={die2} rolling={rolling} />
    </div>
    <button
      className={handleBtn}
      disabled={this.state.rolling}
      onClick={this.roll}
    >
      {this.state.rolling ? 'Rolling' : 'Roll Dice!'}
    </button>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default Dice;
```

My this script causes an error

> Line 7:3:    'defaultProps' should be declared outside the class body  react/static-property-placement

Comment: useful article which can help you debug: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-react-default-props-5c50401ed37d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

declare outside class

```
Dice.defaultProps = {
  sides: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'],
};
```

Example

```
 class Dice extends React.Component{}
 Dice.defaultProps = {
      sides: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'],
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an eslint error for this rule:

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/static-property-placement.md

If you prefer static properties then you can change the rule configuration in your `eslintrc` to prefer your original code class static properties:

```
"react/static-property-placement": ["error", "static public field"]
```